# recovering deleted data sources ssrs-2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have deleted by mistake a data source folder. A forder where many data sources were.

two questions:

1) how can I find the reports that need a data source that was on that folder?

2) is there any way I could recover that data source folder?

thanks and regards
Marcelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a backup of the Report Server database you just need to restore it and the data sources will be there.

To find which reports are using a datasource you can run this query on the ReportServer database:

```
select *
from catalog
where 
content is not null 
AND convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary(max), content)) LIKE '%<DataSourceReference>%' + @yourDataSource + '%</DataSourceReference>%'
```